# How to add Shapes to Slides between Sections with Counting

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to add shapes to the slides between sections (with the section number as text in the shape)  but I know so far only how to find those with that layout name. I think I should setup a counter somewhere but I have not found a way how.
Ideally I would count the sections and then pass the value later to other parts of the macro to be developed.

```
Sub Navigator()

Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oSlideNavigator As Slide
Dim oShapeNavigator As Shape
Dim Section_N As Integer



    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If oSlide.CustomLayout.Name = "Section" Then
        Set oShapeNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddTable(2, 2, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=200, Height:=2)
            oShapeNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 128, 128)

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to add shapes to all slides that are NOT based on the layout called _Section_?

Comment: @John, yes, I edited the question before seeing your comment. I would add the the shapes in the slides that are not `Section`, but keeping the section number in mind, so later I can assign properties selectively. (i.e. different colors etc.)

Comment: @John,I was thinking to ReDim oSlide to an array, and there add the counter, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Set the counter for each slide with Layout Name "Section", then sent the value to the table to be added in those different from those found. So a simple `Else` did the trick.

```
Sub NavigatorX()

'Dim SectionXArr() As Long
Dim oSlide As Slide

Dim SectionX As Slide
Dim SectionXArr As SlideRange ' was ReDim
Dim oShapeNavigator As Shape
Dim NavSlide As Slide
Dim nCounter As Long
'Dim NavSlides

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer

For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

    If oSlide.CustomLayout.Name = "Section" Then
        nCounter = nCounter + 1
        
        ElseIf nCounter > 0 Then
            Set oShapeNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddTable(1, 1, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=200, Height:=2)
        oShapeNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 128, 128)
        With oShapeNavigator.Table

            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    With .Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                        .Text = "Section " & nCounter
                    With .Font
                        .Name = "Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed (Headings)"
                        .Size = "14"
                    End With
                    End With
            Next iColumn
            Next iRow
        End With

        
    End If

Next oSlide

End Sub
```